# mysql remove last characters is character if its number

Tags: mysql

From select statement, in a filed I want to remove last characters is character if its number. Is there string function available in MySQL?

for these two SQL I want

> test

as output

```
select 'test1';
select 'test';
```

Comment: is there any chances that you have values like this? `test12`, `test123` or until 1 numeric only?

Comment: I am looking to remove only last character, fo test123, I want test12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use `REGEXP`,

```
SET @val = 'test12';
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(@val, CHAR_LENGTH(@val) - 1), 
              IF(RIGHT(@val, 1) REGEXP '[0-9]' = 0, RIGHT(@val, 1), ''))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9965)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*another example*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93e21/1)

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last character if it's numeric, one way to do this without using a regular expression is with `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `LENGTH` :

```
select if( right(yourfield,1) = 0 && right(yourfield,1) != '0', 
           yourfield, 
           left(yourfield, length(yourfield) - 1))
from yourtable;
```

To replace all trailing numeric values, you can use `REVERSE`:

```
select if( cast(reverse(yourfield) as signed) = 0 && right(yourfield,1) != '0', 
           yourfield, 
           left(yourfield, length(yourfield) - length((reverse(yourfield) + 0))))
from yourtable;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ebf8/1)

When casting fields as integers/signed in MySQL, it will cast all the numeric characters up to the first non-numeric character -- thus making the `REVERSE` work.  If the last character is not numeric, it results in 0.

Using the `IF` check above, if the last character isn't numeric, then it prints the original value, else it prints all but the last character.

Answer (score 0):

here is a pointer:

use a union between two queries.

in the first - either use REGEX, or grab the substr of the field where another substr for the last char is a number,

then union the text field where the substr of the last char is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Regular Expressions inside MySQL. This package might help you https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp. However, I do not recommend to do it inside MySQL statement as it might be slow. You would better to do it after grabbing the value inside your programming language.